# Sum of multiple float points number

Tags: c, algorithm, floating-point, sum

I write a algorithm to get the sum of float points number, and this algorithm works perfect for integer but when I applied to float points, the sum I got is a negative number. however my array of float points does only have positive float points number. here I post my code, thank you for checking it.

```
static unsigned int do_heap_sum(double ary[], unsigned int n,
                double *result)
{
    unsigned int j;
    int counter=0;
    double sum=0;
    double min;
    while(n>counter){
          make_heap(ary,n);
          min=ary[0];
          sum=sum+min;

          for(j=1;j<n;j++){
              ary[j-1]=ary[j];
          }
          counter=counter+1;
     }   

    *result=sum;
    //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    return 0;
}
```

in this code, I use the make_heap to find the min. do you think this has problem? (this make_heap works perfectly with integers extracting the min of array).
thanks again.

Comment: Is the `make_heap()` provided by standard library or your own implementation?

Comment: What does `make_heap` do? Does it modify the array? If it doesn't modify the array, do you have to call it every iteration?

Comment: `ary[j-1]=ary[j];` It seems like you're accessing beyond the effective range.

Comment: How big are the numbers? Have you checked that you are not simply getting an overflow?

Comment: Please edit your post and add the working version with integers (if that version was working for real) and make_heap function (if not standard). I'm not sure if you are using this *result pointer properly, because pointers are passed to function by value, so you can't read *result outside of function. If so, I don't know why you use this as a pointer.

Comment: Minor: `counter`, `j` and `n` should be the same type.

Comment: make_heap put the min number in the position[0]( sure for int, but not sure for float point ; overflow is not a issue, because the other algorithm can get the right answer.

Comment: check if you output the result correctly. for example if you use printf/sprintf did you change %i,%d to %lf ? if the result is really negative then add breakpoint to + operation of the sum and step until the result gets negative then you will see what really happen

Comment: @python: The use of a pointer is okay. C doesn't allow multiple return values (unless you define a struct for that) and it is quite usual to store results of a function in pointers. Here, you'd define `double res;` and call the function like this: `do_heap_sum(ary, n, &res);`. Now the function can access a local variable of the calling function via the pointer.

Comment: @MOehm You are right. I incorrectly assumed that he want to access local pointer, so he need pass pointer to a pointer to the function.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your code, you want to calculate sum of the heap which stored in `double[]`, so `make_heap` is superfluous, a simple loop is enough.
2. Make sure `double` is big enough to save the sum.
3. For `ary[j-1] = ary[j]` in `for(j=1;j<n;j++)`, why not just swap `ary[0]` and `ary[n - counter - 1]` then adjust the heap in next loop, it's much cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that you used an integer version of make_heap:

```
void make_heap(int *ary,size_t n);
```

instead of a double precision float version:

```
void make_double_heap(double *ary,size_t n);
```

Otherwise, I notice that you sort a heap of size n, n times: that's too much work. What happens when some elements of ary are duplicated ?

You could rewrite the loop:

```
static unsigned int do_heap_sum(double ary[], unsigned int n,
            double *result)
{
    unsigned int counter=0;
    double sum=0;
    double min;
    while(n>counter){
          make_double_heap(ary+counter,n-counter);
          min=ary[counter];
          sum=sum+min;
          counter=counter+1;
     }   

    *result=sum;
    return 0;
}
```